# Model class for Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I have this model class to collect data from firebase database. To show the data I am using firebaserecycleradapter.

**News.class**

```
public class News {

private String message, author, thumb_author, type;
private Long timestamp;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

public String getThumb_author() {
    return thumb_author;
}

public void setThumb_author(String thumb_author) {
    this.thumb_author = thumb_author;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}


}
```

But the problem is there is another child named images that consist of pushId and an Object. This is how it looks

```
news {
      message:"value"
      author:"value"
      thumb_author:"value"
      type:"value"
      timestamp:"value"
      images {
              pushId01:"value"
              pushId02:"value"
              pushId03:"value"
              pushId04:"value"
              pushId05:"value"
             }
      }
```

So my question is how can I add the image child to the news.class or is there any possible solution for this? My possible solution for this is to get the image child data inside the onBindViewHolder using databasereference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property to represent the `images` node. Since these are simple string key/value pairs, you can represent it with a `Map<String,String>`. So:

```
public class News {

    private String message, author, thumb_author, type;
    private Long timestamp;

    public Map<String,String> images; // this is a new field for the images

    public String getMessage() {
       return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    ...
```